# C# Generic Type Inference With Multiple Types

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following generic method for serialising an input object of one type as a super-type as follows:

```
public string SerialiseAs<TResult, TInput>(TInput input) where TInput : TResult
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TResult));
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    ser.WriteObject(stream, input);
    stream.Position = 0;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I have to call this method specifying both generic types as follows:

```
MySubType x = new MySubType();
string json = SerialiseAs<MySuperType, MySubType>(x);
```

My question is, why can't `TInput` be inferred in this situation? Is it because `TResult` isn't actually used as the return type? The following code is cleaner but won't compile because of the missing input type:

```
MySubType x = new MySubType();
string json = SerialiseAs<MySuperType>(x);
```

Comment: C++ much? If only C# had (member) typedefs. I'd like that. But no, it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is, why can't TInput be inferred in this situation?

It can - it's `TResult` which can't be inferred, and there's no way of specifying "partial" inference.

What you *can* sometimes do is separate the type parameters into ones for a generic *type* and ones for a generic *method*, so you'd end up with:

```
// Explicitly state TResult, and infer TInput
Serializer<MySuperType>.Serialize(x);
```

Comment: That makes much more sense. I like the idea of having the output type specified at the class-level but the input type inferred though. Then I can still have the inheritance check on the generic `Serialise` method. I could also try using a fluent syntax like `Serialise(x).As<MySuperType>()`, but that's probably a bit complex for what I'm actually using this for.

Comment: @AdamRodger: It would be tricky that way round, as when you specify `TResult` *second*, you can't impose the `TInput : TResult` constraint. If you didn't mind losing the compile-time constraints, that wouldn't be a problem of course.

Comment: Marked as answer as the actual reason is that you can't partially-specify generic types.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just write it like this:

```
public string SerialiseAs<TResult>(TResult input)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TResult));
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    ser.WriteObject(stream, input);
    stream.Position = 0;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Since `TInput` derives from `TResult`, you really don't need to specify at all.

Comment: This doesn't work with `DataContractJsonSerialiser`, hence why I changed the method to take both types. When you pass your instance as `MySuperClass` then any extra properties in `MySubType` are omitted from the serialised result. You also don't get the `__type` attribute in your output, which I need. You have to pass your instance as the sub-type but tell it to serialise as the super-type.

Comment: @AdamRodger - That's odd. I don't see any way how the `DataContractJsonSerializer` could determine the type of the variable you pass it. The `WriteObject()` method takes a simple `object` as its parameter. Are you sure about this?

Comment: Yep, absolutely certain. I also have a `Serialise` method that doesn't do the type-shuffling as the above method and with the same input they both produce different output. The `__type` attribute is missing.

Comment: @AdamRodger - Works like a charm for me: [http://pastebin.com/4gTfrvuy](http://pastebin.com/4gTfrvuy) Are you perhaps doing some magic with Known Types or something? I'm not much familiar with WCF, but it required me to put this odd `KnownType` attribute on class A before it would work. It also said something about a `DataContractResolver` in the exception message.

Comment: Yeah `MySuperType` is an abstract class with a number of implementing sub-classes (specified via `KnownType`). You need the `__type` attribute added automatically so that you can deserialise at the client. I didn't think that particular detail was important as I had a working method, just interested as to why I couldn't infer the input type. This is only a little helper method for use in my unit tests anyway so I can check required attributes are there and non-required default attributes are omitted etc.