# Is is possible to make a generic method with two type arguments only infer one of them?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method like `public static TOut Method<TIn, TOut>(TIn in)` with constraint `where TIn: class, Interface<TOut>`.

Do I always need to write `Method<ClassIn, ClassOut>(ObjectIn);` when I use it, or is there some way to make the `TIn` inferred by arguments so I only need to write `Method<ClassOut>(ObjectIn);`? The `ClassOut` varies from time to time so I can't write a static class for it every time.

Also, is it right that C# cannot infer types from the constraints so it is impossible to make both `TIn` and `TOut` inferred?

Comment: You could put it into a static generic class `MyClass<ClassOut>` then you only need to specify `ClassOut` because the method will be inferred

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partial generic type inference possible in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893698/partial-generic-type-inference-possible-in-c)

Comment: @Charlieface Seems not. It looks like a different story as I don't use extensions and the answers use `this` argument to infer the type. Also, my question was not clear enough that the `ClassOut` is not a fixed class but more like a type argument.

Comment: Similar issue though, it's caused by the same compiler problem. But perhaps this link is better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719557/c-sharp-generic-type-inference-with-multiple-types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you always need to specify both types. Type inference only works when you specify all the type arguments.

Yes, the C# compiler cannot infer types based on constraints. It can only infer the types based on the types you pass in as arguments.

On a side note, [there is an open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1349) about improving type inference in this regard, however it doesn't seem to have high priority.